# Google maps event listener for circles in array; whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps, for-loop

As the title says, the event listener not working and no errors in console, anyone know whats wrong with my code?

I'm trying to add circles for every object in the JSON that looks like this (sorry for the unformatted json, did it to save room)

```
[
    {
        "zoneTitle": "Zone1",
        "zoneLat": 57.704468,
        "zoneLng": 11.96499,
        "challengesInZone": [
            {
                "challengeId": "1",
                "challengeTitle": "CHALLENGE TITLE: Seek the unknown!",
                "challengeContent": "CHALLENGE CONTENT: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus id nisi eu leo placerat consectetur. Ut congue ut tellus eu tempor. Curabitur rutrum enim vel elit mattis, vel aliquet tellus congue. Nunc a commodo ex. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum a blandit orci. Suspendisse lobortis ac nisl quis tristique.",
                "challengeAnswer": null,
                "challengeStartDate": "2018-05-01 11:45:00",
                "challengeEndDate": "2018-09-30 12:00:00",
                "challengeLat": 57.704942,
                "challengeLng": 11.963954,
                "challengeImageUrl": null,
                "rewardTitle": null,
                "rewardImageUrl": null,
                "rewardContent": null,
                "rewardActiveFrom": null,
                "rewardActiveTo": null,
                "rewardSupplierTitle": null,
                "rewardLat": 0,
                "rewardLng": 0
            },
            {
                "challengeId": "2",
                "challengeTitle": "CHALLENGE TITLE: We are the new old!",
                "challengeContent": "CHALLENGE CONTENT: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus id nisi eu leo placerat consectetur. Ut congue ut tellus eu tempor. Curabitur rutrum enim vel elit mattis, vel aliquet tellus congue. Nunc a commodo ex. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum a blandit orci. Suspendisse lobortis ac nisl quis tristique.",
                "challengeAnswer": null,
                "challengeStartDate": "2018-05-01 11:45:00",
                "challengeEndDate": "2018-09-30 12:00:00",
                "challengeLat": 57.70362,
                "challengeLng": 11.968133,
                "challengeImageUrl": null,
                "rewardTitle": null,
                "rewardImageUrl": null,
                "rewardContent": null,
                "rewardActiveFrom": null,
                "rewardActiveTo": null,
                "rewardSupplierTitle": null,
                "rewardLat": 0,
                "rewardLng": 0
            },
            {
                "challengeId": "3",
                "challengeTitle": "CHALLENGE TITLE: Ship the lipstick!",
                "challengeContent": "CHALLENGE CONTENT: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus id nisi eu leo placerat consectetur. Ut congue ut tellus eu tempor. Curabitur rutrum enim vel elit mattis, vel aliquet tellus congue. Nunc a commodo ex. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum a blandit orci. Suspendisse lobortis ac nisl quis tristique.",
                "challengeAnswer": null,
                "challengeStartDate": "2018-05-01 11:45:00",
                "challengeEndDate": "2018-09-30 12:00:00",
                "challengeLat": 57.705912,
                "challengeLng": 11.959035,
                "challengeImageUrl": null,
                "rewardTitle": null,
                "rewardImageUrl": null,
                "rewardContent": null,
                "rewardActiveFrom": null,
                "rewardActiveTo": null,
                "rewardSupplierTitle": null,
                "rewardLat": 0,
                "rewardLng": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "zoneTitle": "Zone2",
        "zoneLat": 57.707263,
        "zoneLng": 11.934827,
        "challengesInZone": [
            {
                "challengeId": "4",
                "challengeTitle": "CHALLENGE TITLE: Castle on the hill!",
                "challengeContent": "CHALLENGE CONTENT: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus id nisi eu leo placerat consectetur. Ut congue ut tellus eu tempor. Curabitur rutrum enim vel elit mattis, vel aliquet tellus congue. Nunc a commodo ex. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum a blandit orci. Suspendisse lobortis ac nisl quis tristique.",
                "challengeAnswer": null,
                "challengeStartDate": "2018-05-01 11:45:00",
                "challengeEndDate": "2018-09-30 12:00:00",
                "challengeLat": 57.704419,
                "challengeLng": 11.929499,
                "challengeImageUrl": null,
                "rewardTitle": null,
                "rewardImageUrl": null,
                "rewardContent": null,
                "rewardActiveFrom": null,
                "rewardActiveTo": null,
                "rewardSupplierTitle": null,
                "rewardLat": 0,
                "rewardLng": 0
            },
            {
                "challengeId": "5",
                "challengeTitle": "CHALLENGE TITLE: One mountain one view!",
                "challengeContent": "CHALLENGE CONTENT: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus id nisi eu leo placerat consectetur. Ut congue ut tellus eu tempor. Curabitur rutrum enim vel elit mattis, vel aliquet tellus congue. Nunc a commodo ex. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum a blandit orci. Suspendisse lobortis ac nisl quis tristique.",
                "challengeAnswer": null,
                "challengeStartDate": "2018-05-01 11:45:00",
                "challengeEndDate": "2018-09-30 12:00:00",
                "challengeLat": 57.713382,
                "challengeLng": 11.937009,
                "challengeImageUrl": null,
                "rewardTitle": null,
                "rewardImageUrl": null,
                "rewardContent": null,
                "rewardActiveFrom": null,
                "rewardActiveTo": null,
                "rewardSupplierTitle": null,
                "rewardLat": 0,
                "rewardLng": 0
            },
            {
                "challengeId": "6",
                "challengeTitle": "CHALLENGE TITLE: Dock!",
                "challengeContent": "CHALLENGE CONTENT: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus id nisi eu leo placerat consectetur. Ut congue ut tellus eu tempor. Curabitur rutrum enim vel elit mattis, vel aliquet tellus congue. Nunc a commodo ex. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum a blandit orci. Suspendisse lobortis ac nisl quis tristique.",
                "challengeAnswer": null,
                "challengeStartDate": "2018-05-01 11:45:00",
                "challengeEndDate": "2018-09-30 12:00:00",
                "challengeLat": 57.710148,
                "challengeLng": 11.950656,
                "challengeImageUrl": null,
                "rewardTitle": null,
                "rewardImageUrl": null,
                "rewardContent": null,
                "rewardActiveFrom": null,
                "rewardActiveTo": null,
                "rewardSupplierTitle": null,
                "rewardLat": 0,
                "rewardLng": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]





var map;
var mapProp;
var url;
var marker;
var markers = [];
var infoWindow;
var circle;
var circles = [];
var start = { lat: 57.694139, lng: 11.918750 };
var infos = [];

function initMap() {
mapProp = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: start,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "hello world"
});
}

function addMarker(lat, lng) {
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    map: map
});
markers.push(marker);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
url = 'https://localhost:44356/challenge/';
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, field) {
        var infoContent = 'BLABLA';
        var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: infoContent,
            maxWidth: 230
        });
        infos.push(info);
        if (field.zoneTitle) {
            circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: map,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(field.zoneLat,
                    field.zoneLng),
                radius: Math.sqrt(field.challengesInZone.length) * 400,
                title: 'Click to zoom'
            });
            circles.push(circle);
        } else {
            console.log("Missing location for this data item");
        }
    });
});

var listeners = function (i) {
    for (var zone in circles) {
        zone.addListener(zone[i], 'click', function () {
            infos[i].open(map, zone[i]);
            zone[i].setMap(map);
            console.log("hej");
        });
    }
    listeners(i);
};
});
```

Comment: Please consider using some JASON formatter ([e.g.: this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)) and edit you post with formatted code. This is really horrible to read.

Comment: Where are you actually adding a listener to the circle?  It doesn't look like your `listeners` function is ever called.  Also, you can't use the `infowindow.open(map, marker);`  syntax with a circle.

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys, never done anything with google maps b4 hence the noobery. Going to play around little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work, this way :)

```
    var map;
    var mapProp;
    var url;
    var marker;
    var markers = [];
    var infoWindow;
    var circle;
    var circles = [];
    var start = { lat: 57.694139, lng: 11.918750 };
    var infos = [];

    function initMap() {
        mapProp = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: start,
            mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "hello world"
        });
    }

    function addMarker(lat, lng) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);
    }

    function listeners(i) {
        i.addListener('click', function () {
            map.setZoom(16);
            map.setCenter(i.getCenter());
            i.setMap(map);
            console.log("hej");
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        url = 'https://localhost:44356/challenge/';
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, field) {

                if (field.zoneTitle) {
                    circles.push(new google.maps.Circle({
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: '#FF0000',
                        fillOpacity: 0.35,
                        map: map,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(field.zoneLat,
                            field.zoneLng),
                        radius: Math.sqrt(field.challengesInZone.length) * 400,
                        title: 'Click to zoom'
                    }));
                    listeners(circles[i]);
                } else {
                    console.log("Missing location for this data item");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```